# AngularJS Unit Testing, Injection and Jasmine spyOn

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm a little confused at how spyOn is being used under-the-covers when it comes to Angular unit tests. Given the following code:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, $q, $rootScope, employeeService, _notifyService_) {
  notifyService = _notifyService_;
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  deferred = $q.defer();

  spyOn(notifyService, 'error').and.callFake(function(message) { return message; });
  spyOn(employeeService, 'searchEmployees').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);      

  vm = _$controller_('MainController');
}));
```

When the controller service is run, there is some initialization code that happens in MainController. Some of which uses employeeService and notifyService. I was surprised that I didn't need to pass in my mocked implementations of these two services to $controller. Why is that? Is spyOn sneakily replacing the values of these services in the provider?

Thanks!